# What is the definition of "copied content"?

Tags: discussion, rejection-reasons

I have just been doing some suggested edit reviewing and I went to "Reject" an edit. When selecting the reason for rejection I noticed a "copied content" option at the top, which has the following description:

> This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper
>   attribution.

I don't remember this before so first question: is this new?

Anyway, it being new or not isn't overly important, but what I am interested in is what is the definition, and when should this reject reason be applied?

- Is there a set amount of content that must be copied to make this flag appropriate? Does it have to be the whole post that is copied?
- Are there any particular types of source that are more qualified as copied content? e.g. Books
- How does this apply for people "quoting" a section of a web page (or other resource) that they have linked?
- What passes as "proper attribution"? Is a link to the source enough?

Comment: No, it is not new. Any edit that content that violates copyright should be rejected. Case study for you: [Tag wiki edits rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148420)

Comment: The point is that Stack Exchange content is licensed on the CC:Wiki license, and any content that cannot be licensed as such should be kept out. *Any* content that the edit suggester has no right to re-license is considered copied content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially if the *whole* post is copied from elsewhere (book, site or so) and doesn't say so (you *don't* have to link to Wikipedia, but do have to say that's where it is from), it is copied content.

A word or two are also not usually enough for a post to not be plagiarized.

Sections of a web page are fine, so long as they are pertinent and form *part* of the post, not the whole thing. If one is using section, they at least put an effort in picking out and assembling them together - this is OK, so long as attribution is given.

Proper attribution - For a book - name of the book. For a site - a link is best, though not essential - it is better to have a link as it allows one to go to the source.

Comment: So this rejects should be wrong ?http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2755062 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2839841

Comment: @bummi - Yeah. For edits like that, even if they _should_ be rejected, that's the wrong reason.